# Is it possible to create a custom stream?

Tags: files, stdout, streaming

I'm not sure what terminology to use here, so bear with me.

I'm writing an application that produces **a lot** of logs.  I thought it would be cool to be able to have my application stream the logs to `foo`, and allow other processes to read from `foo` as though it were a stream (like `/dev/random`).

That is, I'd like to just continuously stream logs somewhere (without having to worry about filesystem stuff like archiving, deleting, etc), and have the ability for other processes to "tap in" to that stream as though it were some endless file.

How do I go about doing this? What is `foo`?

Ideally:

```
terminal 1
> mkthing foo
> while :; do echo 'abcdefg' >> foo; sleep 1; done

terminal 2
> echo foo
(outputs "abcdefg" every second)
```

Comment: I would say `foo` in this architecture is probably kafka.

Comment: Is there not a native structure in Linux that acts as a "pipe" where I can put data in, and others can read from it, but it does not persist that data?

Comment: maybe DBUS could work. Edit: also natively there are named pipes

Comment: For this use case if it's not native, it's not worth the effort. I'd like processes to read from it as though it were just a never-ending file stream, with no 3rd party tools needed.

Comment: I think you can use FIFOs ( named pipes )  file to handle this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutely normal way to look at the logs is to **write them to a file**. When you want to see the logs, read the file. To watch lines as they get appended to the file, use a command such as [`tail -f`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)#File_monitoring), which, after it reaches the end of the file, keeps it open and watches for extra lines that get appended to it. The option `-f` is for “follow”, and in [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) you can have the same effect with `F` for ”follow“; in other programs this may be known as “tailing” a file because `tail` is the classic utility that does this. See [the `tail` tag on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/tail/info) for more information about tailing utilities.

If you absolutely don't want to write the logs to a file, you can run the application in [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). To run `/usr/bin/my_application --some-option` in the background, with screen:

```
screen -S myapp -d -m /usr/bin/my_application --some-option
```

To watch the logs:

```
screen -S myapp -d -r
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach, i.e. to stop watching the logs. While you're watching the logs, you can also send input to the application, which may or may not desirable. To grant only read-only access, see [Is there a way to run 'screen' in read-only mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-there-a-way-to-run-screen-in-read-only-mode/62209#62209)

With tmux, to start the application:

```
tmux new-session -s myapp -d /usr/bin/my_application --some-option
```

To view the latest logs:

```
tmux attach -r -t myapp
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach. Run `tmux attach` without `-r` to be able to interact with the application.

---

A [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) is not what you want. I'm just mentioning it because it superficially looks appropriate (and as I write it's popping up in comments). It will do what you describe:

```
mkfifo foo
while :; do echo 'abcdefg' >> foo; sleep 1; done
```

in parallel with

```
cat foo
```

This is not what you want because there has to be exactly one reader. If there's no reader, the writing side will block. If there are multiple readers, each line (or chunk, depending on how the program produces output) will be seen by exactly one reader, chosen more or less randomly. If there's a reader and it goes away, the writing side will fail to write and will receive a SIGPIPE if it hasn't disabled them.

Comment: Files are the obvious way to go, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it wihout having to manage the files at all (eg: deleting, archiving, etc.)  But, seems this is the best option. I had hoped there was some system-level "piping" feature, which would seem pretty useful for having processes "broadcast" data.  I guess not.  What happens if treat the file as a buffer -- after it reaches a size whenever I add to the end I also remove from the beginning.  Would `tail -f` still work?

Comment: @JS_Riddler Yes, it would. There _is_ a system-level piping feature: it's called a pipe. But as I explain, that doesn't work for you, because what you want is _not_ a pipe. A pipe gets clogged if there's nowhere for the content to go out.

Comment: Having a more robust "pipe" system seems like a missed opportunity. I can image it being very useful for broadcast/subscribe within a single machine.  I guess appending to file + cron to cleanup will suffice.